# Elastic Search how to select columns and pass filters?

Tags: elasticsearch, put

I can connect to elastic search `http://1.2.3.4:8888/index1/` and query it with e.g. (`PUT` in Body of request):

```
{ 
        "key_u" : "u", 
        "key_p" : "p",  
        "zip": [ "1234"]     
}
```

Response is:

```
{
    "network_level": {
        "0": [
            "12",
            "23",
            "45" 
        ],
        "6": [
            "660771009"
        ]
    },
    "tin": {
        "123": {
            "name": "mike",
            "latlon": [
                ""
            ]
        },
        "456": {
            "name": "john",
            "latlon": [
                ""
            ]
        }
}
```

How do I select `network_level` that is `6` (tried adding it as additional line in a query string but does not change result - it still shows all of them)? 
How do I select to show only specific fields in result?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your current query?

Comment: try "_source": [network_level.6 ]

Comment: @Val - Current query is first 3 lines at the top (key_u, key_p, zip).. That returns response.

Comment: That's not a query, I'm afraid, it looks like a document. A query is some JSON DSL you send to the `_search` endpoint.

Comment: How can I see all documents against `_search` endpoint? Do I need to use GET method (since so far I only have example of a PUT method)?

Comment: @Joe , let me know if my answer solves ur queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [match_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) query to see all the documents against `_search` endpoint. Also for selecting `network_level.6` in your match all query, you can use the below query.

```
{
    "_source": "network_level.6",
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.